# Have I transcribed the paragraph 英国孩子学习中文的热情…… correctly?

Tags: transcription

One of my iTalki teachers is getting me into watching the news, and thus I'm trying to work out what [this CCTV video](https://tv.cctv.com/2019/08/14/VIDE8GVIMtj2zToPRDSahHMj190814.shtml) says.  Here's my transcription:

> 在海外越来越多的家长选择让孩子学习中文，尤其在英国。无论是私利还是公利幼儿园或者小学，中文课已经成为了热门的课外兴趣班。我们来看路透社的报道。
>
> **英国孩子学习中文的热情从丫丫学语的那刻便开始培养了。不少幼儿部门机构和当地的幼儿园小学合作，从为不满周岁的婴儿设计教师班，到为大龄孩子设置的中文识字课，都有涉及**。
>
> 我现在位于的是伦敦圣玛丽小学。在我身后呢，将近有十余名英国的孩子，他们刚刚完成了中文课程，而他们的年龄是在5～8岁，他们来这里学习怎么唱中文歌，怎么识中文字。
>
> 有教育机构表示，他们的课程分散在伦敦6座学校中，常在周末以及假期开办。在暑期有8余名1～4岁的孩子前来学习。在针对5岁～8岁年龄段孩子的课程中，老师会在一个半小时内从发音到笔画，以讲故事做游戏的方式去教给孩子四至五个汉字。
>
> 让他们自己发明自己的动作，他们特别喜欢我问他们，怎么做水饺的动作。他们每个人都很踊跃地去想，诶我的水饺是这样，我的水饺是那样，这样子。
>
> 伦敦的幼儿中文教育学程竞争力进几年不断增大。他们提供的课程为一至一个半小时价格大约是15英镑，相当于人民币130元左右。在市场中处于中等的价位。早在2016年9月，英国教育部启动了卓越汉语教学项目，并投资1000万英镑用来推广中文学习。据统计，去年已经有超过3500名学生选择把中文作为英国初中毕业考试的科目。

I think I've understood most of it, but the second paragraph is problematic.  It means something like:

> English kid's enthusiasm for studying Chinese is cultivated from the beginning [丫丫学语?].  A number of kindergarten departments and local kindergartens and primary schools are cooperating, from designing class for not-yet-1 infants to character recognition classes set up for older child, they are all involved.

**Question**: Have I transcribed the paragraph 英国孩子学习中文的热情…… correctly?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 丫丫学语 is wrong. It should be 呀呀学语, [which means the expression of the baby babbling to learn the words of adult](https://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?wd=%E5%91%80%E5%91%80%E5%AD%A6%E8%AF%AD&query=%E5%91%80%E5%91%80%E5%AD%A6%E8%AF%AD&srcid=28232&from=kg0)s. For the other parts, I think your understanding is good.